# What is meant by signing a block of data in shred file systems. I am making a project where I am to demonstrate public auditing of shared data

Tags: encryption, parallel-processing, cloud, distributed-computing, shared-data

I am making a project wherein I need to demonstrate the public auditing of shared data. For example Let's say I have a large text file which is shared by some users. And each users signs some block of data. What is meant when they say data blocks in my case of large text file. What is meant by when they are signing it And how is it verified when someone access the text file. Please help me I have been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: *What is meant when they say data blocks in my case of large text file* We'd need much more context to know what **exactly** that phrase means for your project. If I had to guess I'd say it means a contiguous sequence of bytes starting at a specified offset and continuing for a specified length. *Signing* is probably a reference to a [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). I'm afraid your question is too vague to give a good answer.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I meant like i have a large file shared among user and someone changes a block of data in it. What does this mean and how can signing prevent it. Like if I have to code how should I break my text data.